# Can a singleton in spring have static methods?

Tags: java, spring, oop, design-patterns, singleton

`Component` and `Service` type beans and most of the other bean types are by default singleton.

In one of my code Pull requests, I declared a method as static in a `Component` as the method wasn't modifying any class level variables.

My code reviewer pointed out that since the class is anyways a Singleton and is going to have a single reference, he said it was unnecessary to make the method `static`, but rather make it a `instance` method.

Which way is the correct way of writing code as most of the classes in my application are Singletons?

Comment: you probably meant not `public`, but an `instance` method; after all you can still have `public static...` methods

Comment: If you want to use a static util method, then just do that.  A singleton's use case is for having a single instance of an object, with functionality exposed through its _instance_ (not static) methods.

Comment: @Eugene thanks. corrected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your reviewer is probably right about this one, it makes little sense to declare a static method inside a singleton; unless this static method is a factory method that returns the singleton instance itself.

I could think of two other reasons not to declare static methods in the singleton : testing is harder for static methods in some cases and you will really confuse the caller of this singleton. He/she might see that there is a static method and have a hard time understanding why it was declared like this, it would require extra reasoning as far as I see for such a method.

Comment: A static method is not really associated with the instance, cannot access instance state, and therefore defeats the purpose of using the singleton pattern in the first place.

Comment: Agreed. My take on this: it's not necessarily 'wrong' but it is unconventional and therefore confusing. Following conventions is an asset for code maintainability.